# combineLatest<{ [id: string]: Book }, string[]> What is this?

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, rxjs, ngrx

```
export const getSearchResults = function (state$: Observable<State>) {
 return combineLatest<{ [id: string]: Book }, string[]>(
  state$.let(getBookEntities),
  state$.let(getSearchBookIds)
 )
 .map(([ entities, ids ]) => ids.map(id => entities[id]));
};
```

What I need explained is this line:

```
<{ [id: string]: Book }, string[]>
```

What in the world is that? I've literally never seen it anywhere before.  What is even worse is some sort of array is being used as a property name I guess.  Also, just in case you talk over my head is there a name for this so I can google it to do further research?  It's from [this](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/blob/master/src/app/reducers/index.ts) ngrx example.  Thanks!

Comment: It's a TypeScript index signature. Search for it in the docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Comment: There's too many concepts involved to give you a comprehensive explanation of what is going on in a single answer. Depending on how familiar you are with static typing, you need to read about parametrized (aka generic) types and structural typing in TypeScript.

Comment: @cartant this document did help but good grief that example is so bad they give.  `interface StringArray {
    [index: number]: string;
}`  Its bad because it's not really showing a special use case scenario.

Answer (score 2):

The line `<{ [id: string]: Book }, string[]>` is so called diamond notation. It means that the function "combineLatest" takes arguments of a generic type that you define within the diamonds.

So it means "take an object with a string key and a value of type Book as first parameter and as second parameter, take an array of string values"

The parameters:

`(state$.let(getBookEntities),state$.let(getSearchBookIds)`

The first parameter is supposed to be of type `{ [id: string]: Book }` and the second parameter must be of type `array[]`.

The general syntax is like:

```
function identity<T>(arg: T): T {
  return arg;
}
```

The function identity is of any type T, takes an argument of type T and returns T.

A sample usage could look like that:

```
var foo = identity<string>("hello");
```

The function identity takes a parameter of string, because you defined it to be string, but you could reuse this function for any type you specify there. it has a return type of string and just returns the passed argument, which is "hello".

(Also see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)

This hopefully helped you understanding.

It is the same as the generic types in Java.